# Is there a version of the Vrkasura/Bhasmasura story in which Mohini tricks him by making him perform Sandhyavandanam?

Tags: sandhyavandanam

there is part when he has to say "Damodara" and put his hand on his head and his boon from Siva burns him to ashes.